# Deque - how come "reserve" doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, stl

The standard STL vector container has a "reserve" function to reserve uninitialized memory that can be used later to prevent reallocations.

How come that the other deque container hasn't it?

Comment: because it dos not reallocate?

Comment: It could be a valid question if you wanted to get all allocation out of the way at the beginning of some operation. However, in that case, you could just use a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Increasing the capacity of a `std::vector` can be costly.  When a `vector` outgrows its reserved space, the entire contents of the vector must be copied (or moved) to a larger reserve.

It is specifically because **std::vector resizing can be costly** that `vector::reserve()` exists.  `reserve()` can prepare a `std::vector` to anticipate reaching a certain size without exceeding its capacity.

Conversely, a `deque` can always add more memory **without** needing to relocate the existing elements.  If a `std::deque` *could* `reserve()` memory, there would be little to no noticeable benefit.

Comment: It also mostly doesn't matter anyway because vector implementations are pretty smart about reallocating

Comment: @CatPlusPlus In practice, I've noticed that it doesn't matter until it does.  :)

Comment: Still, resize would be really useful in some applications.  We have a realtime robot control loop, and we aren't allowed to use memory allocation in it. We can use a vector, because we can get all the memory allocation to happen in the constructor. It would be nice to be able to use a deque in there, where we know that the number of elements will always be less than a limit.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Won't it be better to use a `std::vector` instead since you know the upper bound for the container?

Comment: Late comment for late readers: If a maximum size is known in advance, dynamic memory allocation is undesired and still we need deque (or queue) semantics then a *ring buffer* is data structure of choice. Unfortunately there's no STL container for, so needs to be implemented on one's own...

Answer (score 9):

For `vector` and `string`, reserved space prevents later insertions at the end (up to the capacity) from invalidating iterators and references to earlier elements, by ensuring that elements don't need to be copied/moved. This relocation may also be costly.

With `deque` and `list`, earlier references are never invalidated by insertions at the end, and elements aren't moved, so the need to reserve capacity does not arise.

You might think that with `vector` and `string`, reserving space also guarantees that later insertions will not throw an exception (unless a constructor throws), since there's no need to allocate memory. You might think that the same guarantee would be useful for other sequences, and hence `deque::reserve` would have a possible use. *There is in fact no such guarantee* for `vector` and `string`, although in most (all?) implementations it's true. So this is not the intended purpose of `reserve`.

Comment: Right! The issues are **invalidation** of iterators and references, as well as the expense of allocating.

Comment: you are wrong,the push_back and insert would always invalidate the iterator.See [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: @bigxiao: interesting, that says iterators are invalidated for `deque` although references are not. So we can still reach the conclusion that reserving space wouldn't make any difference to invalidation.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

> As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.
>   The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as needed. **Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a std::vector because it does not involve copying of the existing elements to a new memory location.**

Deque can allocate new memory anywhere it wants and just point to it, unlike vectors which require a continuous block of memory to hold all their elements.

Comment: cplusplus dot com is terrible fyi and you shouldn't use it, link to it or acknowledge its existence in any other way

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I've never heard that before, I use it constantly and have never had problems before, why is is bad?

Comment: Wrong content that can't be updated by any means. cppreference.com is an actively maintained wiki for this purpose.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Never realised that, i'll switch sites! Thanks for the info, i'll update the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Only `vector` have. There is no need of reserve function for deque, since elements not stored continuougusly and there is no need to reallocate and move elements when add, or remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

reserve implies allocation of large blocks of contiguous data (like a vector). There is nothing in the dequeue that implies contiguous storage - it's generally implemented more like a list (which you will notice also doesn't have a 'reserve' function).

Thus, a 'reserve' function would make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main types of memory: memories that allocate a single chunk like array and vectors, and distributed memories whose members grabs any empty location to fill in. queue and linkest list structures belong to the second type and they have some special practical advantages such that deleting a particular element does not cause a mass memory movement as opposed to arrays and vectors. Therefore they do not need to reserve any space beforehand, if they need it they just take it by connecting to tip

Answer (score -1):

If you aim for having aligned memory containers you could think about implementing something like this:

```
std::deque<std::vector> dv; //deque with dynamic size memory aligned vectors.

typedef size_t[N] Mem;
std::deque<Mem> dvf //deque with fixed size memory aligned vectors. Here you can store the raw bytes adding a header to loop through and cast using header information and typeid... 
//templates and polymorphism can help storing raw bytes, checking the type where a pointer points for example, and creating an interface to access the partial aligned memory.
```

Alternatively you can use a map to access the vectors instead of a deque...

Comment: this use case you describe is what custom allocators are for...